# Apps monitoring on Openshift

Tags: openshift

Once I have deployed my application on Openshift, what is the recommended way / best practice of collecting the: 1) CPU, 2) network, 3) memory, 4) disk storage usage of the app? Basically to monitoring an app.

The best would be if they could be displayed in a time series format. Is it possible to link it with 3rd party service (e.g. New Relic) to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. Sorry I didn't clarify on the question, I am actually the admin deploying Openshift Origin. My clients will be deploying apps on it. I want to monitor these apps' resources usage on our servers. If possible, to monitor if applications are responding within reasonable time frame. In this case, I don't have full control on the app source code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that new relic would be the best way to go for most folks. OpenShift does have a marketplace that brings in lots of different 3rd-party solutions like and makes them super easy to integrate. New Relic is available and best of all you can do it for free. You can go to marketplace.openshift.com to add new relic and there's even a KB that will walk you through it step by step here: https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/203467070-How-do-I-add-New-Relic-to-my-application-in-the-OpenShift-Marketplace-.

For the sake of stackoverflow, here are the contents of that article:
1. Go to marketplace.openshift.com and login in
2. Locate New Relic
3. Click on "Try the Free Edition"
4. Complete checkout steps.

This will create your www.newrelic.com account. You can confirm this by going to
purchased products at the top of the page. Then to your new relic add-on and click on "New Relic". This should bring you over to newrelic.com and automatically log you in with your OpenShift marketplace account.

To add New Relic to an individual OpenShift application.

1. Click on Purchased Products
2. In the New Relic Section, you should have something like "newrelic_6a260 Standard" and a "add to apps" button.
3. Click on the "add to apps" button
4. Select the application you want to add New Relic to.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please refer to my comment after the question. I am the service provider deploying Origin. So I am more looking for a tool on platform level to monitor apps and the underlying servers resource usage.

Answer (score 1):

There are two other options you can use.

1. AppDynamics - I have used their tools and I really like it for monitoring. It is available as well through the Online Store
2. DataDog - I have not used them but I have seen the demos at their booth and it looks really good as well.

Would love to hear what you choose and your experience.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider [Sysdig Container Monitoring](https://www.sysdig.com/openshift-monitoring)

Of all the tools mentioned, it's the only one that was purpose-built for containers. It uses the metadata from openshift to allow you to group containers dynamically into services (namespaces, deployments, etc).

It gives you host, container, and application metrics, including response time of containers and services using network data.

It provides custom alerting and dashboarding as well.

Finally, if you're the service provider, they have a functionality that enables "service-based access controls" - basically allowing you to limit data access to certain services, again, based on the Openshift's metadata.

Sysdig can be used as a cloud service or as on-premise software depending on your use case. Here is a link to their open shift commons briefing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-w-OD78Hno0